# SMB 3.0 file share storage limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, storage, san

What is/are the limitation/s to move from SAN storage to SMB 3.0 on windows Server 2012 - SQL server 2012 enterprise production environment?

I want to know the benefit of using SAN over SMB 3.0 as well ?

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind the following: generally SAN in sthe best option for clustered environments. In non clustered Environment you can opt for locl disks. 
Moving from SAN/Local Disk to SMB Windows share can hide some potential problems.

Using SMB network connectivity becomes a very very important piece of your architecture. Probalby you will have to use dedicated nics on database server. You have to consider who/what is sharing disks through SMB. Especially if the "sharing" server is a cheap NAS, you have to pay attention about performance and to the number/weight of all other clients.

The best uses for SMB share are:

- build low cost clustered environments, specially when you have lightweight
  databases
- Test/Disaster recovery/developement environments;
- Storing historical data;
- Emergecy/temporary storage;
- During database migration/upgrade processes.

If you want to use SMB in production environment I think you have to build a strong network infrastructure:

- Nics redundancy;
- Dedicated nics;
- impement traffic isolation (VLAN implementation);
- Buy robust NAS solution;
- COnsider involving 10GB network interfaces;
- Keep under control network performance, check periodically network interfaces counter. Tune parameter like MTU to obtain the best performance for your physical infratructure.